# Trigger minimize event from code on JFrame

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java app, I have a JFrame that I need to minimize automatically once the app starts, hide it from the taskbar and show it on the system tray instead. Currently I've made it appear on the system tray but minimizing the JFrame manually. I've tried using the following two options:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
setVisible(false);
```

but it didn't work out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be a OS-specific implementation, so I don't think it's something that will be easily accomplished with Swing/JavaFX.  You'd have to use something like Java Native Access (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) or something with JNI (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to do this, and fwiw this is hardly trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by “didn't work out”?  What did setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED) do that did not meet your expectations?

Comment: If you decide to look for something native based (via JNI) take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org - it is supposed to save peoples time while getting familiar with JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is OS X version specific. However, this code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package simple;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author michalo
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

works exactly as expected.

It opens new JFrame and minimise it.

I am using Java:

java version "1.8.0_11"

macOS: 10.10.5

The code above is auto generated by NetBeans.